# Google Sheet: Show first data validation value if cell is empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Good afternoon everyone,

I am looking for a way for my dropdown list to show the first value if the cells **A18** and **F18** are **empty**. The data validation range is from cell **X18** to **AA18** (4 values).

So basically, when I enter the name 'Test', it will fetch the data: "Healer", "Tank", "Paladin" and "Mixed DPS" from another tab and display it in the cells X18 to AA18. Using data validation a dropdown list is being generated with these values. However, as soon as I enter a name, I want the default value of the dropdown list to be the value of **X18**.

So: if A18 is empty, the value of F18 should be matching X18. (if no name is given, there wont be anything in F18 so it should stay empty)

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet?

Comment: @Iamblichus https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lbWrNKPIX71X7UdUhQErujqJHngCrEmLpCoGnBCcyRw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I just noticed your last two sentences seem to contradict. "However, as soon as I enter a name, I want the default value of the dropdown list to be the value of X18.

So: if A18 and F18 is empty, the value of F18 should be matching X18." So you want X to be the default value when A:F is blank, or when A has a name?

Comment: Also if A18 and F18 are empty, there is no default value to be populated from the drop down because there is no data being fetched in X:AA. If you could just clear this up for me I can post more solutions.

Comment: I edited the last sentence:
If A18 is empty, the value of F18 should be matching X18. (if no name is given, there wont be anything in F18 so it should stay empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly just put the formula in Cells F18:F.

```
=IF($A18<>"",$X18,"")
```

If column A is not empty then fetch the value in column X, otherwise blank (or select from dropdown). Take a look at the sheet you linked, I have updated it.

Selecting from the dropdown will overwrite the formula, if this is the issue you're referring to your only fix is to create a helper column or utilize scripts.

[image]

**UPDATE**

In order to accomplish this with scripts you can add the following:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var editRange = { // A18:A250
    top : 18,
    bottom : 250,
    left : 1,
    right : 1
  };

    //Get sheet from which the event occured
  var range = e.range
  var sheet = range.getSheet();  

    // Exit if wrong sheet
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "War Board") return;

    // Exit if we're out of range
  var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) return;

  var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
  if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right) return;

  //Set default if value is not blank
  if (!range.isBlank()) range.offset(0, 5).setValue(range.offset(0, 23).getValue());

  //Set blank if value is blank
  if (range.isBlank()) range.offset(0, 5).setValue("");
}
```

This will set the value of F to the corresponding value in X column if a name is given in column A. If the cell in column A is emptied it empties cell F.

Comment: Hello Kevin, thank you for your solution. I have thought about this too, but whenever you change the value of the dropbox, the formula will be overwritten. So if you then remove the name, the dropdown list wont clear itself.

Comment: It sounds as though you want to have the first value be defaulted of the drop down list when a name is selected. Otherwise leave it blank?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I don't know if it is possible with a foruma.. I think a script is needed for that. But I have no clue.

Comment: I gave you a script that should be what you're looking for. Unfortunately you cannot default a data validation box with a formula so it will always be blank even when it's populated with items. The only solution outside of a script is to use the formula previously provided, but as you noticed that will be overwritten.

Comment: This works, thank you very much for your time!